# What to do about a dispute within edits?

Tags: discussion, edits, users

Looking at the [revision history for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16657435/revisions), there are two users who appear to have been going back and forth about the best way to edit a particular piece of the post (mainly, the formatting of the error text) by way of editing the post repeatedly.

While overall, I feel constructive editing is a good thing (I made an edit myself, which <strike>has yet to be overturned</strike> was quickly shot down by Meta), is this too much? I also understand that nobody is perfect, so multiple amendments may happen from time to time. However, I see two problems with this particular situation:

- Too many edits lead to an auto-wiki conversion, which in and of itself is not a bad thing, but were the question a very good one, the new user could potentially lose out on some very beneficial new user rep.
- Both editors have missed multiple, more pertinent, grammatical errors on their multiple corrections.

As for the the formatting they seems to fixated on, I would be happy either way, and that's not what this question is about.

**Rather, what should be done in response to the editors' actions?** I admit, I don't recall ever running into this kind of situation before, but I've also never actively looked for it. I see three main options to be taken:

- Who cares?

  - This is something too minor/localized to be of any consequence.
  - I should just edit, ignore the previous edits, and walk away.
- This needs immediate action!

  - I should flag something related to this question to alert a mod to the low-quality editing?
  - I should make a comment on the question, hoping the editors will catch on. (likely not, but just throwing the idea out there...)
- I'm not sure...

  - I should post a question on Meta letting others make the decision for me.

Obviously, I'm here now, but for next time, what should one do in this situation?

Comment: If there's an edit war, flag for moderator attention. They can lock the post temporarily. If a post does turn auto-wiki and it shouldn't be, flag for a moderator's attention and they can revert it back.

Comment: @Luke yes, post as answer, not comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there's an edit war, first try leaving a comment to one of the editors (editors can be pinged by comments). If the edits don't stop, flag the post for moderator attention. Moderators can lock the post temporarily<sup>1</sup>.

If a post does turn auto-community-wiki and it shouldn't be, flag it for a moderator's attention and they can revert it back.

*<sup>1</sup> They can also lock a post indefinitely, but they normally won't do that in the case of an edit war.*

Comment: Editors get notified for `@username` comments, even if they haven't posted a comment in the question. It might make sense to try and talk to the editors before calling the cavalry. Especially on SO.

Comment: Good point. In my answer I was just supposing this is an all-out edit war with no intentions of stopping.

Comment: @Yannis I had no idea the @ comments worked that way. Thanks!